# How to fetch Parent and child items completely, Python 3.6

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

[The way I am able to fetch all the details, can I even be able to fetch the sub datasets name which are present in the providers dataset? I wish to have providers name followed by dataset name and further followed by datasets present in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxNQN.png)[The below image link gives the hierarchy of one provider, similarly we have many providers, can I fetch all the details using API for all the providers?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNBA2.png)[This is the output .csv which I am able to fetch the details after running the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl9qg.png)[The below image gives the details about one provider named "AMECO" in which I am unable to fetch the Datasets title and child datasets, in turn able to fetch sub-child items.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUlpA.png)The below code is working efficiently, but few parts of the for loop is not fetching the correct 
information. Can someone please help me. I want to fetch all the data set's which is present in[It is the link which provides the information about the Proviers](https://db.nomics.world/providers)the provider's list. In turn; main datasets title i am not able to get in the csv file.

```
import requests, os, sys, csv
import pandas as pd list
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 10000)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```

Below are the links which gives the information about the Providers.

```
URL_1 = 'https://db.nomics.world/providers'
URL_2 = 'https://db.nomics.world/'

Required_Columns = ['Provider', 'Region', 'Website', 'In DBnomics since', 'Updated by DBnomics on', 'Dataset Name', 'Link']

print('\n> Retrieve DBNomics Providers')

DBN_Providers = []

Response = requests.get(URL_1)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(Response.content, 'html.parser')
for Class_L1 in Soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'my-8 sm:flex sm:flex-wrap sm:-mx-4'}):
    for Class_L2 in Class_L1.findAll('h2', {'class' : 'mb-2 font-bold text-grey-darkest text-xl group-hover:underline'}):
Provide_Code = Class_L2.text
Provide_Code = Provide_Code.strip()
DBN_Providers.append(Provide_Code)
print('\n>> Total Providers:', len(DBN_Providers))
Details_All = pd.DataFrame()
for I, Provider in enumerate(DBN_Providers, start=1):
URL = URL_2 + Provide
print('%s > %s : %s'%(I, Provider, URL))
Meta_Data = {}
Meta_Data['Provider'] = Provider
Response = requests.get(URL)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(Response.content, 'html.parser')
# Meta Data
for Class_L1 in Soup.findAll('dl', {'class': 'dl-properties'}):
TList = []
for Item in Class_L1.findAll('dd'):
Item = Item.text
Item = Item.strip()
TList.append(Item)
Meta_Data['Region']  = TList[0]
Meta_Data['Website']  = TList[1]
Meta_Data['In DBnomics since']  = TList[2]
Meta_Data['Updated by DBnomics on'] = TList[3]
Meta_Data = pd.DataFrame([Meta_Data])
# Dataset Details
Dataset_List = []
for Class_L1 in Soup.findAll('div', {'id': 'category-tree'}):
for Class_L2 in Class_L1.findAll('ul', {'class': 'list-reset mb-6'}):
for Class_L3 in Class_L2.findAll('details', {'class': 'my-4'}):
for Class_L4 in Class_L3.findAll('a', {'class': 'mr-1'}):
TList = []
Dataset_Name = Class_L4.text
Dataset_Name = Dataset_Name.strip()
TList.append(Dataset_Name)
HREF = Class_L4.get('href')
TList.append(URL_2 + HREF.strip())
Dataset_List.append(TList)
Dataset_DF = pd.DataFrame(Dataset_List, columns=['Dataset Name', 'Link'])
DF = pd.concat([Meta_Data, Dataset_DF], sort=False)
DF = DF.sort_values(['Provider'], ascending=[True])
DF = DF.fillna(method='ffill')
DF = DF.dropna(subset=['Dataset Name'])
Details_All = Details_All.append(DF, sort=False)

Details_All = Details_All.drop_duplicates()
Details_All = Details_All[Required_Columns]
Details_All.to_csv('Details_All.csv', index = False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Use `API` make your life easier [API LINK](https://api.db.nomics.world/v22/providers/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `API` and scrape whatever you need:

```
import requests
import csv

r = requests.get('https://api.db.nomics.world/v22/providers/').json()

data = []
for item in r['providers']['docs']:
    item = (item['code'], item['region'],
            item['website'], item['converted_at'][0:10], item['name'], f"https://db.nomics.world/{item['code']}")
    data.append(item)


with open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(['Name', 'Region', 'Website',
                     'Updated by DBnomics on', 'Dataset Name', 'Link'])
    writer.writerows(data)
    print("Operation Completed")
```

View Output Online: [click here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/4fe632ff3bce64362e91eba85b7fda43/output.csv)

Also you can loop over the data by the provider name below:

https://api.db.nomics.world/v22/providers/AMECO

Something like:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.db.nomics.world/v22/providers/AMECO').json()

for item in r['category_tree'][0:]:
    pop = [oka['name'] for oka in item['children'][0:]]
    print(pop)
```

Output:

```
['Population', 'Labour force statistics', 'Unemployment', 'Employment, persons (national accounts)', 'Employment, full-time equivalents (national accounts)', 'Self-employed, persons (national accounts)', 'Wage and salary earners, persons (national accounts)', 'Wage and salary earners, full-time equivalents (national accounts)']
['Private final consumption expenditure', 'Private final consumption expenditure per head of population', 'Actual individual final consumption of households', 'Consumer price index', 'Total final consumption expenditure of general government', 'Collective consumption expenditure of general government', 'Individual consumption expenditure of general government', 'Total consumption']
['Gross fixed capital formation, total economy and sectors', 'Gross fixed capital formation at current prices, sectors', 'Net fixed capital formation, total economy', 'Net fixed capital formation at current prices, sectors', 'Consumption of fixed capital, total economy', 'Consumption of fixed capital, general government', 'Gross fixed capital formation by type of goods at current prices', 'Gross fixed capital formation by type of goods at constant prices', 'Gross fixed capital formation by type of goods, price deflators', 'Change in inventories and net acquisition of valuables', 'Gross capital formation', 'Gross saving', 'Net saving']
['Domestic demand excluding change in inventories', 'Domestic demand including change in inventories', 'Final demand', 'Contributions to the change of the final demand deflator']
['Gross national income', 'Gross national income per head of population', 'Net national income', 'National disposable income at current prices', 'Gross national disposable income per head of population']
['Gross domestic product', 'Gross domestic product per head of population', 'Gross domestic product per person employed', 'Gross domestic product per hour worked', 'Potential gross domestic product at constant prices', 'Trend gross domestic product at constant prices', 'GDP at constant prices adjusted for the impact of terms of trade per head', 'Contributions to the change of GDP at constant market prices', 'Alternative definitions domestic product at current prices', 'Gross value added, total economy']
['Compensation of employees', 'Taxes linked to imports and production and subsidies, total economy', 'Operating surplus, total economy', 'Nominal compensation per employee, total economy', 'Real compensation per employee, total economy', 'Adjusted wage share', 'Nominal unit labour costs, total economy', 'Real unit labour costs, total economy']
['Net capital stock at constant prices, total economy', 'Factor productivity, total economy', 'Production factors substitution, total economy', 'Marginal efficiency of capital, total economy']
['Exports of goods and services', 'Imports of goods and services', 'Exports of goods', 'Exports of services', 'Imports of goods', 'Imports of services', 'Terms of trade']
['Balances with the rest of the world, national accounts', 'Balances with the rest of the world, BOP statistics']
['Foreign trade at current prices', 'Foreign trade shares in world trade']
['Employment, persons', 'Employment, full-time equivalents', 'Wage and salary earners, persons', 'Wage and salary earners, full-time equivalents', 'Gross value added by main branch at current prices', 'Gross value added by main branch at current prices per person employed', 'Gross value added by main branch at current prices per employee', 'Gross value added by main branch at constant prices', 'Gross value added by main branch at constant prices per person employed', 'Gross value added by main branch at constant prices per employee', 'Price deflator gross value added by main branch', 'Compensation of employees by main branch', 'Nominal compensation by main branch per employee', 'Adjusted wage share by main branch', 'Nominal unit wage costs by main branch', 'Nominal unit labour costs by main branch', 'Real unit labour costs by main branch', 'Industrial production']
['Exchange rates and purchasing power parities', 'Interest rates']
['Revenue', 'Expenditure', 'Balances']
['Revenue', 'Expenditure', 'Balances']
['Revenue (ESA 2010)', 'Expenditure (ESA 2010)', 'Net lending (ESA 2010)', 'Excessive deficit procedure']
['Based on potential GDP (ESA 2010)', 'Based on trend GDP (ESA 2010)']
['Based on ESA 2010', 'Based on ESA 2010 and former definitions (linked series)']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But, can I fetch whole and sole list of providers at a time? As you have worked with one provider "AMECO" then there are 62 providers. So, is it possible?

Comment: you may not be able to get them all at once but if you make use of threads you can greatly increase the number you get per time hence speeding up the process considerable @manasakulkarni

Comment: @maestro.inc Can you please help me out.